# SubView(nib) wont remove after calling removeFromSuperView()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an overlay view to segregate content, I'm checking for authentication in viewWillAppear() and I have a Notification subscribed to my Auth method. If I authenticate before any of my other views appear the overlay does not show up, however it does on the first view and will not go away even after calling removeFromSuperView().

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ProtectedViewController: UIViewController, ForceSignInBannerDelegate, 
SignUpViewControllerDelegate, LoginViewControllerDelegate{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkAuthentication), name: .myNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
     self.checkAuthentication()

}

func checkAuthentication() {
    let bannerViewController = ForceSignInBanner.instanceFromNib() as! ForceSignInBanner
    bannerViewController.delegate = self

        if (!AuthenticationService.sharedInstance.isAuthenticated()) {
            self.setView(view: bannerViewController, hidden: false)
            print("Need to login")
        } else if(AuthenticationService.sharedInstance.isAuthenticated()) {
            self.setView(view: bannerViewController, hidden: true)
        }
    }

func setView(view: UIView, hidden: Bool) {
    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { _ in

        view.isHidden = hidden
        if hidden {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            self.view.addSubview(view)
        }

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to remove a new `ForceSignInBanner` each time. Ideally you should create it once and keep a reference to the `ForceSignInBanner` created (as an optional property of `ProtectedViewController`).

Then remove the `ForceSignInBanner` that you've stored in the property.

```
    class ProtectedViewController: UIViewController, ForceSignInBannerDelegate {

        // This lazily loads the view when the property is first used and sets the delegate.
        // Ideally you wouldn't force-case the `as` but I've left it for simplicity here.

        private lazy var forceSignInBannerView: ForceSignInBanner = {
            let forceSignInBannerView  = ForceSignInBanner.instanceFromNib() as! ForceSignInBanner
            forceSignInBannerView.delegate = self
            return forceSignInBannerView
        }()

        // ... your other code ... //

        fun toggleForceSignInBannerViewVisibility(isVisible: Bool) {
            if isVisible {
                view.addSubview(forceSignInBannerView)
            } else {
                forceSignInBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I somehow figured it out I will also try your implementation.